# Bitnami Apache rewrite Rewrite Cond and Rule

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I would really appreciate some help in rewriting something.
I have moved a site to a sub domain and now the links to that site are not working.

The link before was:
`https://www.domainname.com/folder/folder/folder/folder/show?elem=icon_file9393`

The new link it needs to redirect to with added sub domain is:
`https://www.subdomain.domainname.com/folder/folder/folder/folder/show?elem=icon_file9393`

the folder names are dynamic
*show?elem=*  will always be there but the *icon_file9393* is dynamic

Any help would be much appreciated

This  is what I am currently trying in /opt/bitnami/apache/conf/vhost/wordpress-https-vhost.conf

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:443 _default_:443>
  ServerName www.example.com
  ServerAlias *
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile “###########”
  SSLCertificateKeyFile “##########”
  DocumentRoot /opt/bitnami/wordpress
  # BEGIN: Configuration for letsencrypt
  Include "/opt/bitnami/apps/letsencrypt/conf/httpd-prefix.conf"
  # END: Configuration for letsencrypt
  # BEGIN: Support domain renewal when using mod_proxy without Location
  <IfModule mod_proxy.c>
    ProxyPass /.well-known !
  </IfModule>
  # END: Support domain renewal when using mod_proxy without Location
  # BEGIN: Enable non-www to www redirection
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)elem=[^&]+(&|$) [NC]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?domainnmae\.com$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^[^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]+/show/?$  https://www.subdomain.domainname.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NC,NE]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^localhost
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+(:[0-9]+)?$
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=permanent,L]
  # END: Enable non-www to www redirection
  <Directory "/opt/bitnami/wordpress">
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
    # BEGIN WordPress fix for plugins and themes
    # Certain WordPress plugins and themes do not properly link to PHP files because of symbolic links
    # https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-wordpress-nginx/issues/43
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^bitnami/wordpress(/.*) $1 [L]
    # END WordPress fix for plugins and themes
    # BEGIN WordPress
    # https://wordpress.org/support/article/htaccess/#basic-wp
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    # END WordPress
  </Directory>
  Include "/opt/bitnami/apache/conf/vhosts/htaccess/wordpress-htaccess.conf"
  # BEGIN: Support domain renewal when using mod_proxy within Location
  <Location /.well-known>
    <IfModule mod_proxy.c>
      ProxyPass !
    </IfModule>
  </Location>
  # END: Support domain renewal when using mod_proxy within Location
</VirtualHost>
```

This is the /opt/bitnami/apache/conf/vhost/htaccesss/wordpress-htaccess.conf:

```
<Directory "/opt/bitnami/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/akismet">
  # Only allow direct access to specific Web-available files.
  
  # Apache 2.2
  <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
  Order Deny,Allow
  Deny from all
  </IfModule>
  
  # Apache 2.4
  <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
  Require all denied
  </IfModule>
  
  # Akismet CSS and JS
  <FilesMatch "^(form\.js|akismet(-frontend|-admin)?\.js|akismet(-admin)?(-rtl)?\.css|inter\.css)$">
  <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
  Allow from all
  </IfModule>
  
  <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
  Require all granted
  </IfModule>
  </FilesMatch>
  
  # Akismet images
  <FilesMatch "^(logo-(a|full)-2x\.png|akismet-refresh-logo\.svg|akismet-refresh-logo@2x\.png|arrow-left\.svg)$">
  <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
  Allow from all
  </IfModule>
  
  <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
  Require all granted
  </IfModule>
  </FilesMatch>
</Directory>
```

Comment: Do you also want `https://www.domainname.com/` to be redirected to `https://www.subdomain.domainname.com/` as well?

Comment: No, it's only the structure of the domain with the 4 /  and ending with elem=icon?* which needs to be redirected. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use this redirect rule in root .htaccess of `domain.com`:

```bash
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)elem=[^&]+(&|$) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?domainname\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?[^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]+/show/?$ https://www.subdomain.domainname.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NC,NE]
```

Query string will automatically be forwarded to the new redirect URL.

Comment: I think i've definetely got it in the right place too, as I have just tested this is working:
  `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/example/(.*)$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://google.com [P,L]`

Comment: Make sure this is your topmost rule just below `RewriteEngine On` line.

Comment: Yep, that is the first rule. Am I missing anything else...?

Comment: What is exact URL are you entering in browser to test this? Also edit your question show your latest .htaccess with this suggested rule.

Comment: I have tested with this rule on my local Apache with the URL you've provided and it got redirected fine.

Comment: I'm using bitnami and editing the /opt/bitnami/apache/conf/vhost/wordpress-https-vhost.conf file. it doens't appear to have a .htaccess file?

Comment: If it is vhost file then use `RewriteRule ^/?[^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]+/show/?$ https://www.subdomain.domainname.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NC,NE]` and restart your Apache after making change.